# What is Harvey's purpose?

Tags: analysis, harvey

In the movie [Harvey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_%28film%29) from 1950 in the ending it is made clear that Harvey actually exists and is a Pooka, some sort of fairy from the celtic mythology.

Apparently he has chosen Elwood P. Dowd as some sort of medium to make people aware of him and contact them in bars every evening. But what is his actual intention?

And has the death of Elwoods mother anything to do with the whole story? If I recall correctly, Elwoods sister said that Harvey appeared after their mother died.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some research and I don't think any particular reason is supposed to be taken away.  Elwood's mother's death probably just made Elwood more acceptable as a medium since he started getting out more and was lonely enough to accept Harvey, although he was an ideal medium in the first place, which is why Harvey chose him to begin with.  Harvey's intention, however, is unclear.